# C# encoding some characters getting replaced by control characters

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the response returned from a web service using the below code.

```
 var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);

 myRequest.Method = "POST";
 myRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
 myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

 var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
 newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
 newStream.Close();

 var objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(myRequest.GetResponse());

 var responseText = new StreamReader(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
```

However in the response the symbols like `*`, `^`, `~`  are getting replaced by control characters `GS`, `US`, `RS`.

I believe it has got something to do with the encoding format.

Edit: Code snippet for request added

Update: tested it with all encoding formats but desired output was not found

Comment: Avoid guessing at the encoding.  Use HttpWebResponse.CharacterSet instead.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the objWebResponse.CharacterSet property returned from the service and it has an empty value.

This is a public service and as per the implementation guidance document the encoding format to be used is UTF8.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are looking at the ContentEncoding property.  If CharacterSet truly is empty then you cannot trust *anything* from that server.  Pick up the phone and call the programmer.  Or experiment with different encodings.

Comment: tested with all encoding formats but desired result was not found. I have updated question with code snippet for request also